# Using Android specific code in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I wish to use android specific code in libgdx. I follow the tutorial in the link: http://carlorodriguez.github.io/blog/2014/10/05/android-platform-specific-code-with-libgdx/

my mainclass is :

```
public class mainclass extends Game implements ApplicationListener {

public ActionResolver mactionResolver;

public mainclass(ActionResolver mactionResolver){

    this.mactionResolver = mactionResolver;


};
@Override
public void create() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    this.mactionResolver.showToast("Hi");  <----here nullpointerexception
    }
```

}

my android actionresolver is:

```
public class actionresolverapp implements ActionResolver {
Handler handler;
Context context;
public actionresolverapp(Context context) {
    handler = new Handler();
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void showToast(final CharSequence text) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

and finally my interface in the libgdx core is:

```
public interface ActionResolver {
    public void showToast(CharSequence text);

}
```

Please why I have the exception in mainclass?

EDIT: here the AndroidLauncher

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication{
actionresolverapp mactionresolverapp;
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mactionresolverapp = new actionresolverapp(this);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    initialize(new mainclass(mactionresolverapp), config);



}
```

}

Comment: Can you add the code of how `mainclass` is created when in Android?

Comment: Please when posting a question about crashing code, paste the actual crashing code with error messages. Providing enough information is vital for other users to answer your questions.

Comment: the code is really that. the line code  this.mactionResolver.showToast("Hi");  work in mainclass constructor and don't work in every other point of the app. the problem seems that mactionResolver isn't visible everywhere eccept that in the constructor of actionresolverapp ....why?

Comment: mainclass not actionresolverapp (sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is right with the interface. The problem may be in the Handler that you are creating in the showToast()

Try:

```
     public actionresolverapp (Activity activity, AndroidApplication application){
            this.activity = activity;
            this.application = application;
        }

void showToast(final String text){
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                application.handler.post(new Runnable() { // This thread runs in the UI
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            });
        }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```